# Question about Green function

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

How to find the Green's function associated to the operator $\frac{-d^2}{dx^2}$ and to the boundary Dirichlet conditions: $u(a)=u(b)=0$ ?

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Away from the singularity, it must be a straight line, no? Try playing with  the absolute value function $|x|$, perhaps shifts and stretches will acheive your goal. Remind us of the integral condition (to 1?) for the Green's function. Note, the Green's function depends on the operator *and* the dimension of your space, as well as boundary conditions.

Comment: It looks like OP means a 1D problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great set of [notes](http://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.303/Green-explicit.pdf) on this exact green's function with identical boundary conditions. They're from an MIT math course. He sketches out the derivation in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The Green function is defined as the function that solves your problem for a $\delta$-distribution. For your problem I'd guess the equation becomes:

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}G(x|x') = -\delta(x-x')$

In free space ($G(x|x')\rightarrow 0 \text{ for } x\rightarrow\infty$ ) this equation is sufficient. For boundary conditions at a finite value of x the boundary-condtitions need te be included in the equation.

The standard trick is by canonically treating the Greens function with the boundary conditions. Now since you have the one-dimensional case you could maybe try to use the [method of image charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges), which should be relatively easy in the 1D-case.